# How to performe parameter validation in SOAP Web service using implementation of Spring Validator interface

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc, soap, spring-validator

I have SOAP web service (CXF2) with 2 methods i want to validate input parameter using implementation of Spring Validator interface
here is my web service method :

```
@Override
@RequestWrapper(localName = "getData", className = "webservice.getMyData")
@WebMethod(operationName = "getData")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "getDataResponse",className = "webservice.getDataResponse")
public void getData(
        @WebParam(name = "keyList") List<String> keyList,
        @WebParam(mode = Mode.OUT, name = "codReturn")Holder<List<CodRetour>> pCodRetour,
        @WebParam(mode = Mode.OUT, name = "result") Holder<List<MyData>> pResult) {
```

is it possible to validate **keyList** using Validator ?